# Abort a long running workflow

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

We are using Windows WorkFlow, WCF and a WPF(kind of a monitoring tool, which will display the status of the report like IN_PROGRESS, FAILED, SUCCESS) in our project.

The workflow will be initiated by WorkFlowApplication in WCF. The Work flow in-turn will be calling a legacy application(report generation app), at times operation in the legacy application will take 4 to 5 hours to complete. The user needs to kill this long running workflow from the wpf application. We tried using WorkFlowApplication Abort, but the report generation is not getting killed. We called the legacy app from the CodeActivity.

Could you please provide what will be the best way to call that legacy app(will be calling a method in that dll) and also to kill that called app when workflow abort is called ?

Thanks & Regards,
Varun

Comment: Can you post some code on how you are calling the legacy app? Does the app provide some kind of Abort method? One option is also to kill the process that is running it.

Comment: We were returning an object from legacy app by calling a method from wf, with the returned object we call a method in legacy app that at times can take 4 to 5 hours to complete. There is no Abort method in that legacy app. We are restricting the workflow to create only 5 instances at a time, so the legacy app(dll) can be running in 5 instances.

Comment: If the legacy app has no way to Abort it, how do you expect to be able to accomplish that in code?  How would you do abort it manually?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is to create a wrapper for the legacy app that can be executed in a separate process (e.g. a console application).
Form the workflow you would then fire the wrapping application, get the process handler and eventually kill it when the WF is aborted.